# You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected error in Module Federation environment

Tags: angular, webpack, rxjs, webpack-module-federation

I've migrated one app to MFE Architecture using Module Federation and mysteriously looking error is thrown at runtime:

`You provided an invalid object where a stream was expected error. You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable`.

The code that causes it looks like this:

```
this
  .getSomeObservable()
  .pipe(
    switchMap(() => this.getOtherObservable()) // switching here causes the error
  ).subscribe()
```

However I was pretty sure code was ok...

When analysing stack trace, error originates from:

> https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.6.7/src/internal/util/subscribeTo.ts

```
export const subscribeTo = <T>(result: ObservableInput<T>): (subscriber: Subscriber<T>) => Subscription | void => {
  if (!!result && typeof result[Symbol_observable] === 'function') {
    return subscribeToObservable(result as any);
  } else if (isArrayLike(result)) {
    return subscribeToArray(result);
  } else if (isPromise(result)) {
    return subscribeToPromise(result as Promise<any>);
  } else if (!!result && typeof result[Symbol_iterator] === 'function') {
    return subscribeToIterable(result as any);
  } else {
    const value = isObject(result) ? 'an invalid object' : `'${result}'`;
    const msg = `You provided ${value} where a stream was expected.`
      + ' You can provide an Observable, Promise, Array, or Iterable.';
    throw new TypeError(msg);
  }
};
```

In my case, `result` is of type `BehaviorSubject`.

However, when I compared stack trace when app is running in non-federated to federated, the issue is here:

> https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/6.6.7/src/internal/innerSubscribe.ts#L110

```
  if (result instanceof Observable) {
    return result.subscribe(innerSubscriber);
  }
```

Without module federation, this `if` is truthy, when I look at prototypes, deeper I can find `Observable`.

However in federated environment, this expression is falsy.

The good news it that refactoring to:

```
this
  .getSomeObservable()
  .subscribe(() => this.getOtherObservable().subscribe())
```

does not throw error any more.

Do you have any ideas how to properly fix it?

Comment: Probably your `getOtherObservable` is loaded from another module, that is not available at that exact moment. It's hard to say without seeing the actual code. By the way, there's an angular wrapper for module federation https://www.angulararchitects.io/en/aktuelles/the-microfrontend-revolution-part-2-module-federation-with-angular/

Answer (score 1):

You need to add 'rxjs/operators' to webpack module federation plugin configuration along with 'rxjs'. Also need to provide expected version as rxjs/operatos is secondary entrypoint and webpack wont be able to find the version automatically.

```
{
  'rxjs': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '^6.5.0'}
  'rxjs/operators': { singleton: true, strictVersion: true, requiredVersion: '^6.5.0'}
}
```

This allows mfe application to share the rxjs operators from app shell which fixes the undefined or mismatch in observable operator streams